# A-frame, Polygon animation

Tags: animation, polygon, aframe

I'm trying to animate a polygon in A-frame, seen also here [Add polygon in A-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968918/add-polygon-in-a-frame):

```
// Create new shape out of the points:
var shape = new THREE.Shape( vector2List );
// Create geometry out of the shape
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
// Give it a basic material
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 1} );

// Create a mesh using our geometry and material
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
// add it to the entity:
this.el.object3D.add( mesh );
```

The goal now is to change the opacity of the shape in an animation. I don't know how to access the shape/polygon attributes within the animation - maybe something like this:

```
// animation
let opacityAnimation = document.createElement( 'a-animation' );
```

following lines are not clear:

```
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'mesh.material', 'opacity' );
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'to', '0' );
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'dur', '5000' );
this.el.appendChild( opacityAnimation );
```

**edit:**

here is a live-example:  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anathapindika/p7jhmn65/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `mesh.material` to `opacity`. I believe You want to specify the animated attribute. As the animation element should look like this:

```
<a-animation attribute="material.opacity"
             to = "0"
             dur = "5000">
</a-animation>
```

Your js must be setting those accordingly:

```
// animation
let opacityAnimation = document.createElement( 'a-animation' );
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'attribute', 'material.opacity' );
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'to', '0' );
opacityAnimation.setAttribute( 'dur', '5000' );
this.el.appendChild( opacityAnimation );
```

---

Now, if you want to use the material component with a custom/polygon geometry, You need to create it a bit differently.

Instead of creating a new mesh, consisting of its own geometry, and material, lets make the geometry in three.js, and use the existing material component.

So i simply replaced adding the new mesh with a simple:

```
var myShape = new THREE.Shape(points);
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(myShape);
this.el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry = geometry;
```

You should wait till the object3D is loaded to do it properly, in my fiddle i just made a simple timeout.

---

Now we can use the animation component as intended, and change the `material.opacity`.

Check it live on a box [here](https://jsfiddle.net/884vs7fa/1/).
Check it live on a polygon [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p7jhmn65/16/).

Comment: thx. I see that working, if you want to change the opacity of something like an a-box. But with a custom shape, this doesnt seem to work. Lets see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Anathapindika/p7jhmn65/ (around line 50)

Comment: You're right, there is no material component in the entity, im not sure how to access the object3D material from the animation entity, i'm trying to set an opacityparameter in the polygon component, but it's not updating properly yet https://jsfiddle.net/p7jhmn65/7/ - if you check out the console, the object opacity is changing, but the model is not updating, i'll check it out after work i guess

Comment: i would appreciate it! since its quite related: do you know an easy approach to change the opacity with a click on the polygon? this.el.AddEventListener('click',clickFunction()) does not seem to work..

Comment: ah - wow! thank you so much!
is there an easy work around to trigger that with a click event?

Comment: @Anathapindika how about setting the `begin` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/p7jhmn65/18/ ?

Comment: @Anathapindika no problem - if You don't have any further questions feel free to mark the question as anwsered :)