# How to create parallelogram using Aframe js?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have been trying to create a parallelogram using Aframe js but i couldn't find primitive to create. Please help me to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it manually, by creating a custom component , which will create a mesh based on a custom THREE.js shape:

```
let points = [];
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(3, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(5, 3));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(2, 3));

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  points[i].multiplyScalar(0.25);
}
var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.el.object3D.add(mesh);
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3brL5744/10/).
Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968918/add-polygon-in-a-frame) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, here is another approach that separates the *'shapemaker'* from the *'shapedata'* so you can just have one script for making whatever custom shape you like and add in the shape-specific data by registering a custom primitive (that uses that component) and passing the shape-specific information from there.

So, a generic shapemaker component (will parse the vertices in the schema when passed from the primitive registration)

```
//register custom shape maker component
AFRAME.registerComponent('customshape', {

    schema: {
        model: {
            default: {},
            parse : function (value){  
                return value
            }
        },   
    },    

    init: function (){

        this.geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var geometry = this.geometry
        var verts = this.data.model
        var faceCount = verts.length/3
        for (var i = 0; i < verts.length; i++) {
            var v3 = verts[i]
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z));
        }       
        for (var i = 0; i < faceCount; i++) {
            a = i*3
            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(a, a+1, a+2))
        }
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        geometry.mergeVertices();   
        this.material = this.el.components.material.material
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.el.setObject3D('mesh', this.mesh);

    },

});
```

Then register whatever shape you want as a primitive (eg parallelogram) and pass in the vertices as a value when you assign the default components

```
//register particular shape primitive and pass in shape specific vertices
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-parallelogram', {
  defaultComponents: {
    material: {},
    customshape: {model: [
        {
            'x': -1,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 0,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 0,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 0,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 0,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        }, 
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 0,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 0,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 2,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        },
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 1,
            'z': 0,
        }, 

    ],
},
  },
  mappings: { 
    color: 'material.color',
  }, 
});
```

And then use that in the HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/simplecustomshapemaker.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-parallelogram position="-1 0.5 -5" color="blue"></a-parallelogram>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

So by using that same custom shapemaker script I could define a number of shapes as primitives without having to change that script.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/up41m16s/2/) is a working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would create any custom shape that I wanted (using parallelogram as example), although Piotr's answer is much more succinct, maybe another approach will be helpful.

First create a custom component that contains all the vertices you need for your shape. (Sorry that vertices makes it long but its clearer whats going on)

```
//register parallelogram component

AFRAME.registerComponent('parallelogram', {

//create schema
schema: {    
},

//define vertices of a parallelogram
//made up of 4 triangles that are combined together
para_vertices: [
    //first triangle
    {
        'x': -1,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    },
    //second triangle
    {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    }, 
    //third triangle  
    {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    },
    //fourth triangle  
    {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 0,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 2,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    },
    {
        'x': 1,
        'y': 1,
        'z': 0,
    }, 

],


init: function (){

    //create 3.js geometry      
    this.geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var geometry = this.geometry

    //get the vertices that we described above
    var verts = this.para_vertices
    //calculate number of faces     
    var faceCount = verts.length/3

    //loop through vertices and add to the geometry
    for (var i = 0; i < verts.length; i++) {
        var v3 = verts[i]
        geometry.vertices.push ( new THREE.Vector3(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z) );
    }
    //add faces to geometry 
    for (var i = 0; i < faceCount; i++) {
        a = i+i*2
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(a, a+1, a+2))
    }
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    geometry.mergeVertices();

    //use out of the box material that you add to the entity in the primitive below
    this.material = this.el.components.material.material
    //make a new 3.js mesh combining the geometry and the material
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    //add this mesh to our parent element
    this.el.setObject3D('mesh', this.mesh);

},

});
```

Then, make a primitive by using that component and the existing material component

```
//make it a primitive by defining a-parallelogram and adding the above component
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-parallelogram', {
  defaultComponents: {
    //add the material component
    // you could define this yourself in the above component if you prefer
    material: {},
    //add the parallelogram component we have just created
    parallelogram: {},
  },
  mappings: { 
    //specify any attributes and their mappings that you would like to be able to define from the html layer
    color: 'material.color',
  }, 
});
```

And you can then use that in your HTML like so

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include a script that contains the parallelogram component -->
    <script src="scripts/parallelogram.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-parallelogram position="-1 0.5 -5" color="blue"></a-parallelogram>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jg5qu245/3/) is a working fiddle

I hope that's helpful, you can find more on creating custom components [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/writing-a-component.md) and in particular for making shapes [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/writing-a-component.md#example-box-component)