# A-frame: How to give a primitive like Ring or Cylinder depth?

Tags: three.js, aframe

Is it possible to give a 2D primitive like Ring thickness/depth? I'm trying to make a 3D door with primitives and I want to make either a ring that has some depth or a cylinder with a thicker mesh. Even if it's at the three.js layer I would like to learn how to do this so I don't have to rely on imported 3D objects for the whole design.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968918/add-polygon-in-a-frame) may be also helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extrude a shape, you will need to use THREE.js. Below is an example for how to do this.
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=extrude#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2

How to use THREE.js geometery inside AFrame?
You make a custom component that creates a new THREE.Geometry, and inside that component, you build your shape and extrude it (see the THREE.js example, click (<>) button in lower right to see the code).

Below is an example that makes a custom quad in a component.
You can see the glitch here.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/custom-quad

Look in the quad.js for details.
You should be able to copy code from the three.js extrude demo, and place it into your custom component init function to build the extruded shape.
Then you can create parameters, like 'thickness', and put them in the schema, and then they can be accessed from the component name on the entity.
If you don't yet know how to write a custom component, you will need to practice this to understand how it works.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html

Here is a snippet from my glitch that makes a custom quad. It shows how to make THREE.Geometry in an AFrame custom component.

```
init: function (data) {

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices = data.vertices.map(function (vertex) {
            var points = vertex.split(' ').map(function(x){return parseFloat(x);});              
            return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]);
        });
        // Build the UVs on the faces.
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push( 
          [ new THREE.Vector2(1,0), new THREE.Vector2(0,1), new THREE.Vector2(1,1) 
],
          [ new THREE.Vector2(1,0), new THREE.Vector2(0,0), new THREE.Vector2(0,1) 
]);
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2));
        geometry.mergeVertices();
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        this.geometry = geometry; 
        //console.log(data);
      }
```

Comment: If you figure this out, and make a cool extruded shape demo, publish it on glitch and share it with us here. We'd love to see it.

Comment: This is great thanks so much! I'll have to play with that this weekend.