# What is the code and what attributes are necessary to create a pyramid in A-frame VR world?

Tags: aframe

I need a pyramid in A-frame world.  How can I use the 'cone' feature to get the shape of a pyramid?

```
    <a-pyramid color="green" height="20" width="30" depth="10" position="0 1 -3"></a-pyramid>


    <a-pyramid color="green" height="20" width="30" depth="10" position="0 1 -3"></a-pyramid>
```

Nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of available primitives in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/) - bottom left.

---

You can start with methods like:

- combining [triangles](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/primitives/a-triangle.html#sidebar):

  ```
  <a-triangle vertex-a="1 0 0" vertex-b="-1 0 0" vertex-c=" 0 1 -0.5"></a-triangle>
  ... and so on
  ```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d301acof/).

- or creating a custom geometry like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968918/add-polygon-in-a-frame) question.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a [cone](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/primitives/a-cone.html#attributes_segments_radial) and reduce the segments to 4

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>

      <a-cone
        segments-radial="4"
        height="2.5"
        position="-1 0 -7"
        color="#9f7d4f"
        radius-bottom="2"
      ></a-cone>

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```